# Viscosity Vs Conduction

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, thermal-conductivity, viscosity

*Viscosity* of a moving fluid (e.g. a gas) is commonly related to the exchange of *momentum* between layers of such fluid moving at different velocities.

Intuitively, one could think that in a gas such transfer happens either via molecules migration across the boundary of the moving layers (e.g. molecules from the faster layer move into the slower) or via collisions among molecules.

*Conduction* instead is related to *kinetic* *energy* transfer within a body. Again, this energy transfer in the above considered gas could be imagined taking act via migration of molecules at different energies, or via collisions.

Some authors agree with this depiction (e.g. [Jacobson MZ, "Fundamentals of Atmospheric Modeling"](https://books.google.it/books?id=FrHcZmwj7JQC)), some instead say that viscosity is due *only* to momentum exchange via molecules migration, and conduction is due *only* to kinetic energy transfer due to collisions (e.g. [Spurs JH & Aksel N,
"Fluid Mechanics"](https://books.google.it/books?id=7_FrhazRTgsC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22momentum%20exchange%22%20collisions%20mass%20viscosity&source=bl&ots=H1i9G2x4de&sig=yrS7l_HzJw7xN4V8YMDR_PIFvzo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk37jn_L3bAhXSI1AKHYphAOEQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=%22momentum%20exchange%22%20collisions%20mass%20viscosity&f=false)).

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your post, viscosity is related to the exchange of momentum in a fluid. More specifically, viscosity is the diffusion coefficient of momentum that tells us how fast momentum diffuses within a fluid. Viscosity can be measured using experiments like the falling sphere method.

Conduction is the diffusion of energy in a medium, typically referring to thermal energy. Unlike viscosity, conduction is not a physical coefficient. In terms of temperature, the equivalent of viscosity would be thermal conductivity.